# MsalServiceException: AADSTS90014: The required field 'aud' is missing

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to access an Azure REST api via a ASP.NET Core 2.2 backend application (another MVC Application). I want to get ***OnBehalfOf*** authentication for the REST api based on the logged in Azure AD user. I get this weird error.

> MsalServiceException: AADSTS90014: The required field 'aud' is
>   missing.

Nowhere in the documentations or in blog posts, I could managed to find a solution or even a slimier issue discussed. Below mentioned is my code.

```cs
public class TokenAcquisitionService : ITokenAcquisitionService
{
    private readonly UserAssertion _userAssertion;

    private readonly ConfidentialClientApplication _confidentialClientApp;

    public TokenAcquisitionService(UserContextInfo userContextInfo, MemoryTokenCache memoryTokenCache, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var tokenCache = memoryTokenCache.GetIDistributedCacheCacheInstance();
        var clientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId");
        var clientSecret = new ClientCredential(configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientSecret"));

        _confidentialClientApp = new ConfidentialClientApplication(clientId, userContextInfo.BaseRequestUrl, clientSecret, tokenCache, null);
        _userAssertion = new UserAssertion(userContextInfo.Token);
    }

    public async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsync()
    {
        string[] scopes = { "https://example.com/846fsd66-xxxx-yyyy-82cb-1fe40a30f00c/user_impersonation" };
        var accounts = await _confidentialClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();

        AuthenticationResult result;

        if (accounts.Any())
            result = await _confidentialClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, accounts.First());
        else
            result = await _confidentialClientApp.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync(scopes, _userAssertion);

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

I'm using the NuGet package `Microsoft.Identity.Client version 2.7.1` for REST API authentication and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` `version 2.1.1` for MVC application's authentication.

**Update**

For the MVC app I'm using Azure Active directory authentication as follows (It uses it's own cookie authentication for my knowledge).

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The description for the error: `AADSTS90014 MissingRequiredField - This error code may appear in various cases when an expected field is not present in the credential.`
Source: [Authentication and authorization error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes).

The field `aud` is for the intended **audience** of the token. And you need that to validate the token was meant for the backend you're sending it to.

Taken from [JSON Web Token Introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/):

> **Registered claims** - These are a set of predefined claims which are not mandatory but recommended, to provide a set of useful, interoperable claims. Some of them are: iss (issuer), exp (expiration time), sub (subject), aud (audience), and others.

Taken from [RFC 7519 - Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1):

> The "aud" (audience) claim identifies the recipients that the JWT is for. Each principal intended to process the JWT MUST identify itself with a value in the audience claim. If the principal processing the claim does not identify itself with a value in the "aud" claim when this claim is present, then the JWT MUST be rejected. In the general case, the "aud" value is an array of case-sensitive strings, each containing a StringOrURI value. In the special case when the JWT has one audience, the "aud" value MAY be a single case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI value. The interpretation of audience values is generally application specific. Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

When configuring Azure Active Directory authentication in the ASP.NET backend you specify the Audience. In our case, the code looks something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = Authority;
    options.Audience = ClientId;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        SaveSigninToken = true
    };
});
```

Where `Authority` was a property containing the `AAD Instance` + our `TenantID` and `ClientID` was the `ClientID` of the application in Azure Active Directory.

When configuring MSAL to talk against an authenticated backend, this looks something like this:

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
  authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT>.onmicrosoft.com',
  clientID: '<CLIENT_ID_GUID>',
  protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap
})
```

Where `protectedResourceMap` contains a map of the API URL and the required scopes.

Comment: Well, I'm not using Jwt authentication for the mvc app. just Azure active directory authentication. Modified the question to reflect that.

Comment: Hi @rickvdbosch hope you find the updates helpful. Thanks in advance.